# Cannot find the 'Manipulate Object Centers Only' button. Is this an addon?

Tags: modeling

Cannot find the 'Manipulate Object Centers Only' button refered to in the book 'Blender Foundations'. Is this an add-on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the "Manipulate Centers Only" button in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154340/where-is-the-manipulate-centers-only-button-in-blender-2-8)

Answer (score 5):

I would post a comment to the above answer, but apparently I need 50 reputation for that so I have to add an answer instead.

The book the OP is referring to is "Blender Foundations: The Essential Guide To Learning Blender 2.6", by Roland Hess. I have this book myself and the text where the author refers to the Manipulate Object Centers Only is in a tutorial where we are trying to box model a simple chair. The effect he wants to achieve is to splay the 4 chair legs out from each other by selecting their bottom faces and using the scale tool:

> However, if you just select the bottom faces of the legs and hit the S
>   key, they will move apart as you scale them up, but they will also
>   grow in size. We'll try a new pivot style to solve the problem. Beside
>   the pivot style menu on the 3D view header is a button called
>   Manipulate Object Centers Only. This magical button causes
>   transformations to only affect object centers, not their component
>   structures. The effect works both in Object mode and Edit mode. In
>   this case, selecting the four faces on the bottoms of the legs and
>   enabling Manipulate Object Centers Only will move the faces away from
>   one another when scaling without actually changing their size.

Note how he mentions the setting works in both Object mode and Edit mode, this seems to imply that we were meant to switch out of Edit mode to Object mode, switch the setting, the come back to Edit mode but he doesn't implicitly tell us this in the book. Having said this,  and after trying it myself this setting doesn't appear to do anything in Edit mode as the above users mention.

Answer (score 3):

When in [*object mode*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects) it should be on the *Header* in the 3D view, next to the pivot point selector:

[image]

Note that you can also toggle it with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (comma).

Comment: It does not appear on the header, which is where I expected it to be. Can't tell when it's on or off using CTL ,   Corrupt install?

Comment: @user2633 Make sure you are in object mode. Is it possible you pressed `tab` or something by mistake and switched modes?

Comment: The book says it should work in both Edit and Object modes, and the step I'm working on is in the Edit mode. Is the book wrong?

Comment: I can't find any commit that removed this option for editmode, and tooltip clearly says *Object and Pose mode only*. What Blender version was the book written for?

Comment: Yup, totally doesn't work in edit mode.

Comment: @Rayzor53 I think the only way to do this in edit mode is by separating the meshes into objects, performing the transform in object mode, and then rejoining the objects.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot of the location]

I found it! Finally able to rotate my objects. But somehow the hotkey [ ALT+, ] doesn't work for me hahaha. solves the problem anyway!

Answer (score -1):

In Blender 2.8 it's at the bottom of the pivot point drop down menu.