# Where is the "Manipulate Centers Only" button in Blender 2.8?

Tags: objects, transforms

I have looked just about everywhere on the Internet and I can't find the answer to this question. Where the hell is the "Manipulate Centers Only" button in Blender 2.8???? It's the the double arrow icon here:

[image]

I seem to have enabled it somehow and I can't scale or rotate my object.

Answer (score 14):

The 'manipulate centers only' has changed again in **Blender 2.81 and newer versions**. It is at the top-right in the toolbar, under the *[Options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/2.90/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/options.html#transform-options)* dropdown. The function is now called *Transform Affect Only > Locations*

[image]

Answer (score 5):

After some searching, I finally found it. For anyone in the future who will be as frustrated as I was, here it is:

[image]

Just click on that, and then it is the "Affect Only: Locations" button at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>.

Comment: There isn't Alt+coma shortcut in 2.8 anymore as well as many other shortcuts removed in default and industry compatible keymaps

Comment: Yes, if you press alt then press "+" it will enable/disable manipulation center points

Comment: No, it will not - by default. This shortcut works in 2.79 and prior. This shortcut does not exist in 2.8 version default keymap and industry compatible keymap. The question is about 2.8. 2.8 can be switched to Blender 2.7x keymap which has Alt+coma shortcut which is not mentioned in your answer and can be misleading.

Comment: alt and plus sign on the numpad did exactly what I wanted - now I can scale to zero in order to align verts - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the (correct) answers given by both *Rob Hoff* and *Whatever*, here are some details about keyboard shortcut customization.

In 2.79 the Python name of this setting was `use_pivot_point_align`, but in 2.8 it was changed to `use_transform_pivot_point_align`.

Knowing that, it is possible to set up a keyboard shortcut for quickly toggling this setting:

[image: 2.8 2.9 custom keyboard shortcut to toggle Pivot Point Align (Manipulate Centers Only)]

(`wm.context_toggle` is specified first when wanting to toggle a setting ON/OFF.)

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.82a

Alt+, not works on MacOS, 
try to HOLD . key -> Only Locations [9]

[image: Blender 2.82a Only Origins]

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it back in if you edit \scripts\startup\bl_ui\space_view3d.py

It's at about line 530:

```
    # Pivot
    if object_mode in {'OBJECT', 'EDIT', 'EDIT_GPENCIL', 'SCULPT_GPENCIL'} or has_pose_mode:
        hack = layout.row(align=True)
        hack.prop(tool_settings, "transform_pivot_point", text="", icon_only=True)
        hack.prop(tool_settings, "use_transform_pivot_point_align", text="", icon='CENTER_ONLY')
```