# Not being able to rotate or scale in blender 2.79

Tags: 3d-view

I'm working on a model right now but it seems I have accidentally pressed a bind, that locks the rotation and scale to be changed in the 3D-View. I can still change it through the Properties menu though.

I have searched on YouTube and found a video that has the solution in it, but only for blender 2.8.

Comment: You probably pushed this button (in the question): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154340/where-is-the-manipulate-centers-only-button-in-blender-2-8

Answer (score 0):

with the item selected in object mode hit "n" opening the tool shelf and showing the transforms. See if the padlock by the problem transforms is closed. if so click on it to unlock it.