# Why can't I scale or rotate objects in the viewport?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, transforms

While it was working a while ago, *scale* and *rotate* is not working in the *3d View* anymore, grab is working though. I'm allowed to scale the objects manually using the <kbd>N</kbd>-key but the shortcuts are not working, no matter how much I press <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd>:

[image: What is wrong here?]

Did I press a key or something?

Comment: make sure that Scale and Rotate are not locked in the N panel > Item > Transform?

Comment: or 3d view options with "affect only locations"?

Comment: I checked but still not working

Comment: do you have any modifiers or contraints on the meshes?

Comment: Have you checked this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160576/19156 ?

Comment: @Alexbries,  no, i didnt added yet

Comment: @lemon, yes thanks, but still nothing...

Comment: @Liz, so upload your file here. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the obtained link in your post.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=PjgaMrSr" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/PjgaMrSr/)

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, uncheck "Affect only locations" option:

[image]

Comment: Oh!, I thought I unchecked that already, hehe...     

Comment: Wow!!!! Thank you so verrryyyy much @lemon!!!!!!!!! You saved me!!!!!

Comment: Hi @Liz! If lemon saved you, consider to accept his answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour