# Moving objects away from 3D cursor equally

Tags: modeling

I know this will be flagged as a repeat question, but all the other questions I have tried the answers. I'm trying to evenly spread objects out from the center, and the answers I've seen are from an old version of blender, and I don't see the button they say needs to press. Here is a video I found from another question of someone showing how to do it, but I can't find that button in the new version. i have found this and when i try to affect only location and scale it from cursor, median, or any other pivot point nothing happens.
[Where is the "Manipulate Centers Only" button in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154340/where-is-the-manipulate-centers-only-button-in-blender-2-8)

[image]

I'm trying to evenly spread out these objects from the center without messing with the scale of the objects.

[image]

@moonboots I know you have the answer like always :)
always a big help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like all your objects origin are at the same position, it must be the reason why the *Affect Only Locations* option is not working, select them all and right click > *Set Origin > To Geometry*.

Comment: That was it. I never thought about the origin being an issue. I knew you would now :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

That option was called "manipulate Only", is now "Transform  Affect Only" and it's under Option > Affect Only.

[image]

Comment: I posted a link to another question answering this and showing that same answer, but it still isn't doing anything on my end. All it does is scale up and down the y axix.